# Change tinymce toolbar icons to text

Tags: tinymce

How can I change tiny mce editor's toolbar icons to text ? [image]

I want these icons to be text buttons.

Answer (score 1):

TinyMCE adds buttons to the toolbar in a variety of places.  The method `addButton` (which is in the `tinymce/classes/Editor.js` file) is the method used to add a button to the toolbar:

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/api/tinymce/tinymce.editor/#addbutton

If you want to change all of the icons to text strings you need to find the code where each button is added to the toolbar and modify the call to `addButton` to not use an icon.

For example, the `print` plugin has this code:

```
editor.addButton('print', {
    title: 'Print',
    cmd: 'mcePrint'
});
```

...which you could change to this:

```
editor.addButton('print', {
    title: 'Print',
    cmd: 'mcePrint',
    text: 'Custom Print'
});
```

You would then see the text `Custom Print` on the toolbar instead of the icon.

*A word of warning - the core editor code adds some buttons, and plugins add some buttons.  If you truly want to replace the icons of* **all** *buttons you will have to modify a fair amount of code in TinyMCE which will make upgrading the editor much harder.*

Comment: Instead of trying to overwrite default buttons, I think it would be better idea to define new alternatives, for example `editor.addButton('myprint', { ...});` instead of modifying `print`. That way you don't need to rewrite anything when you upgrade TinyMCE to more recent version. Of course, you need to redefine your toolbar and menus to use your own variants of the commands instead of the default ones.